# reach xml tags under the same name using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml file with a structure like this:

```
<xml>
<tag>
   <name>paul</name>
   <value>1</value>
</tag>
<tag>
   <name>mary</name>
   <value>2</value>
</tag>
<tag>
   <name>john</name>
   <value>3</value>
</tag>
<xml>
```

My question is, how could i reach each tags value tag using xpath?

Comment: Have you read this nice article? [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all `<value>` within `<tag>` :

```
/xml/tag/value
```

If you meant to get `<value>` by value of `<name>` as stated in your comment, you can do something like this :

```
/xml/tag[name='paul']/value
```

Above example will return `<value>1</value>`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
/xml/tag[name ='paul']/value

/xml/tag[name ='mary']/value

/xml/tag[name ='john']/value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use predicates to uniquely access a value

First element:
/xml/tag[1]/name

Last element:
/xml/tag[last()]/name

etc.

Comment: Is it possible to reach the value tags by name name tag, not knowing the correct sequence

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of the whole value elements:

```
//tag/value
```

but if you don't need the wrapping value element, just the values within the  tags:

```
//tag/value/text()
```